# Create nodes during startup using string input from database as node name

Tags: anylogic

I would like to create a network via code at start up similar to the example in the following link.
https://anylogic.help/markup/create-network-by-code.html

However, I might have 100s of nodes and I was hoping to read in the node name and the x,y,z coordinates from a database. Is that possible?

I'm not quite sure of the syntax to create node based on a string. I tried the following but obviously doesn't work because pn is a PointNode type and the name is a String type. Also it's trying to declare pn twice. But hopefully it explains what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

```
// Init variables
double x, y, z;
PointNode pn;
      
// Read from database
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(node_coord)
    .list();

// Loop for all nodes
for (Tuple row : rows) {
    
    pn = row.get( node_coord.name );
    x = row.get( node_coord.x_coord );
    y = row.get( node_coord.y_coord );
    z = row.get( node_coord.z_coord );
    
    pn = new PointNode();
    pn.setRadius(5);
    pn.setLineColor(red);
    pn.setPos(x, y, z);

    //Add to network
    n.addAll(pn) ;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PointNode` elements do not have a name, so you cannot assign one.

So you can simply loop across your dbase entries and ignore that name:

```
// Read from database
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(node_coord)
    .list();

// Loop for all nodes
for (Tuple row : rows) {
    pn = new PointNode();
    pn.setRadius(5);
    pn.setLineColor(dodgerBlue);
    pn.setPos(node_coord.x_coord, node_coord.y_coord);

    //Add to network
    n.addAll(pn) ;      
}
```

If you want to use names, you should create an agent type "MyNodes" with a String param `p_Name` and another param `p_MyNode` of type `PointNode`. But that is a separate endeavor from this question